# How to allow a dot (.) in htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my htaccess file, and for some reason this rule: RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)$ ./profile.php?name=$1  doesn't allow dots in the link. It allows any other symbol, but not the dot (.). How can I fix this?

```
Options -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:VIA}                 !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:FORWARDED}           !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:USERAGENT_VIA}       !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X_FORWARDED_FOR}     !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:PROXY_CONNECTION}    !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:XPROXY_CONNECTION}   !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTP_PC_REMOTE_ADDR} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTP_CLIENT_IP}      !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]

DirectorySlash On

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /404.php
ErrorDocument 502 /brb.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /profile\?name= [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]


RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)$ ./profile.php?name=$1 


RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)\.php - [F,L,R=404]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

On my website, users can register with any name (thus any character).
But let's say I put my fictional name to be "Mr.BoogieMan.", the link to my profile should be www.website.com/profile/Mr.BoogieMan. But since the dot is in my name, htaccess won't let that go through.

Comment: Do any `/profile/` redirects work? For example, does `http://www.website.com/profile/noDOThere/` work as expected?

Comment: Yes. It works as expected.

Comment: New tactic: why do you think the problem is in your htaccess rewrite rule? There's nothing in your rule that I can see that would interact with a dot. Is it possible your PHP is having the problem?

Comment: Because when I was echoing out the get param, I wouldn't get a dot in that echo.

Comment: That is a totally different problem! Which is good to know because it means we're getting closer. The fact that you get "MrBoogieMan" in $name in profile.php means that the redirect is working. Can you turn on rewrite logging? That will be the best to determine if the problem is in Apache or in PHP. If you turn on rewrite logging and access "Mr.BoogieMan" you should see a log entry either with the dot or without the dot. With the dot means your problem is in PHP, without the dot means the problem is in some rule other than the final one.

Answer (score 3):

Dot (.) is a special character in regular expressions meaning "any character". To use a dot (.) you must escape it like so:

```
\.
```

Comment: I have tried RewriteRule ^profile/([^/\.]+)$ ./profile.php?name=$1  but no luck.

Comment: you've included the dot in your negated character set `[^/\.]` which means you do not allow dot after the slash in profile. Is this what you're looking for? Can you edit your question with an example of a link you are trying to rewrite?

Comment: No, I want to allow the dot in the url. I have editted the post. The last part.